# Problem while adding user private contacts by batch request

Tags: c#, graph, exchange-server, bad-request, batching

I try to add User Contacts by batch request.

After asking Google, I found this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/graphapi-batching/batching-requests-to-msgraph/

I coded a function like the example and got this:

```
public static void importRelevantContactsToUserWithBatch(Manager manager)
{
        List<Contact> succesful = new List<Contact>();
        List<Contact> failed = new List<Contact>();

        int limit = 1;
        int counter = 0;

        var user = users.Where(x => x.Mail == manager.Email).FirstOrDefault();

        var contacts = getRelevantContactsForManager(manager);

        foreach (var contact in contacts)
        {
            var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();
            var requestUrl = graphServiceClient.Users[user.Id].Contacts.RequestUrl;
            System.Console.WriteLine($"RequestURL: {requestUrl}");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl) 
            {
                Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact.toGraphContact()), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };
            System.Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact.toGraphContact()));
            var requestStep = new BatchRequestStep(counter.ToString(), request, null);
            batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(requestStep);
            var returnedResponse = graphServiceClient.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
            returnedResponse.Wait(-1);
            var response = returnedResponse.Result.GetResponseByIdAsync(counter.ToString());
            response.Wait(-1);

            if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                succesful.Add(contact.toGraphContact());
                System.Console.WriteLine($"{contact.toGraphContact().Id} wurde hinzugefügt");
            }
            else
            {
                failed.Add(contact.toGraphContact());
                System.Console.WriteLine($"{contact.toGraphContact().Id} konnte nicht hinzugefügt werden");
            }

            counter++;
        }   

}
```

Running this code, I got a 400 BadRequest as response.

Can someone give me a hint where my problem is I can't find it

Thanks in advance

The tenant is a O365, the request uses a application authentication with all rights granted, the deletion of contacts by batching works fine so in my opinion the mistake must be within this lines:

```
var requestUrl = graphServiceClient.Users[user.Id].Contacts.RequestUrl;
                System.Console.WriteLine($"RequestURL: {requestUrl}");
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl) 
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact.toGraphContact()), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                };
```

Serialized Contact JSON:

```
{"AssistantName":null,"Birthday":null,"BusinessAddress":{"City":"Friesoythe","CountryOrRegion":"DE","PostalCode":"26169","State":"NIE","Street":"Zeppelinring 9","AdditionalData":null,"ODataType":null},"BusinessHomePage":"","BusinessPhones":null,"Children":null,"CompanyName":"Appel  ","Department":"","DisplayName":"Thomas Appel","EmailAddresses":[{"Address":"tappel@stalleinrichtungen-appel.de","Name":"Thomas Appel (tappel@stalleinrichtungen-appel.de)","AdditionalData":null,"ODataType":null}],"FileAs":null,"Generation":null,"GivenName":"Thomas","HomeAddress":{"City":"Friesoythe","CountryOrRegion":"DE","PostalCode":"26169","State":"NIE","Street":"Zeppelinring 9","AdditionalData":null,"ODataType":null},"HomePhones":null,"ImAddresses":null,"Initials":null,"JobTitle":"","Manager":null,"MiddleName":null,"MobilePhone":null,"NickName":null,"OfficeLocation":"53,0191543°7,8857305","OtherAddress":null,"ParentFolderId":null,"PersonalNotes":null,"Profession":null,"SpouseName":null,"Surname":"Appel","Title":null,"YomiCompanyName":null,"YomiGivenName":null,"YomiSurname":null,"Extensions":null,"ExtensionsNextLink":null,"MultiValueExtendedProperties":null,"MultiValueExtendedPropertiesNextLink":null,"Photo":null,"SingleValueExtendedProperties":null,"SingleValueExtendedPropertiesNextLink":null,"Categories":["proALPHA_Export"],"ChangeKey":null,"CreatedDateTime":null,"LastModifiedDateTime":null,"Id":null,"ODataType":"microsoft.graph.contact","AdditionalData":null}
```

Comment: As per the documentation- There are few Prerequisites & setup, To run the sample you need an O365 tenant and a (dev) user account, AD belonging to the O365 tenant in use, Add a local.settings.json etc. Additionally the amount of steps in a batch is currently limited to ony 20 items (!). Try to debug and see in which line of code the exception occurs.

Comment: The step where the exception is thrown at the exchange server so it tells in the returnmessage"404 Bad request" but there is no information what of my request made him struggeling

i added some data and hope it helps to answer my question and helps you to understand where i have done something wrong